# Django, интеренет-магазин, корректировка цены товаров от курса валюты

Tags: python, django, интернет-магазин

Начал заниматься python и Django в частности, решил написать свой интернет-магазин. 
Есть класс "категория товаров", дочерний класс "продукты" в котором указываются цена и остальные атрибуты товаров.
Вопрос в следующем, хочу сделать автоматический пересчет цен товаров при вводе курса валют в админке, но не знаю как это реализовать.
Буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 1):

Можно нагородить что-нибудь такое

**settings.py**

```
DISPLAY_CURRENCY = 'RUR'
```

**models.py**

```
from datetime import date

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class Currency(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Обозначение')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'валюта'
        verbose_name_plural = u'валюты'


class ExchangeRate(models.Model):
    base = models.ForeignKey(Currency, verbose_name='Базовая валюта')
    quoted = models.ForeignKey(Currency, verbose_name='Котируемая валюта')
    at = models.DateField('На дату')
    value = models.DecimalField('Значение')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'котировка'
        verbose_name_plural = u'котировки'


class CatalogItem(models.Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'товар'
        verbose_name_plural = u'товары'

    def price_at(at_date, for_currency):
        rate = (ExchangeRate.objects
                            .filter(base=self.itemprice.currency,
                                    quoted=for_currency,
                                    at=at_date)
                            .first())
        return self.itemprice.value * rate.value if rate else 0

    @property
    def price(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_price'):
            default = Currency.objects.get(name=settings.DISPLAY_CURRENCY)
            if self.itemprice.currency == default:
                self._price = self.itemprice.value
            else:
                self._price = self.price_at(date.today(), default)
        return self._price


class ItemPrice(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(CatalogItem, verbose_name='Товар')
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency, verbose_name='Валюта')
    value = models.DecimalField('Значение')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'цена в валюте'
        verbose_name_plural = u'цены в валюте'
```

Тогда

```
item = CatalogItem.objects.get(pk=1)
print(item.price)
```

будет выводить цену по сегодняшнему курсу и легко будет получить цены любого товара на любой день. Для автоматического заполнения таблицы обменных курсов можно написать [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) и ежедневно запускать [кроном](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Только к вычислению свойства `price` стоит добавить более серьёзную обработку ошибок, чем вывод 0 при отсутствии актуального обменного курса.